# Capturing data from a ProBrowser control with WinAPI

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I'm attempting to read the lines off of a control in an unmanaged application.  I've been using the ManagedWinapi to wrap pinvokes, and for the most part it's gotten me where I need to be.  I can find the control (it's a ProBrowser class, not sure exactly what that is) and view properties, but none of the information I need is available.  Instead, the ProBrowser has nine child elements, all textboxes with matching properties: `Password: false, MultiLine: false`, and `Text: <blank>`.  I'm assuming these are the column headers, but there's not much to go off of.  This is as far down the chain as I'm able to get, and at no level do I seem to have access to the actual contents of the list.

```
SystemWindow list = new SystemWindow(ptr); // latching onto the ProBrowser

SystemWindow[] pieces = list.AllDescendantWindows; // same results if using .AllChildWindows

foreach (SystemWindow y in pieces) {
    ManagedWinapi.Windows.Contents.TextContent tc = (ManagedWinapi.Windows.Contents.TextContent)y.Content; // ListContent returns null here and on the parent control
    Console.WriteLine(tc.LongDescription);
    Console.WriteLine(tc.ComponentType);

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in tc.PropertyList) {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + kvp.Key + ", " + kvp.Value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\tText: " + GetText(y.HWnd));
}
```

`GetText` is simply a wrapper for `GetWindowText`.  It returns text for other controls like buttons just fine, but it doesn't pull anything from the ProBrowser.

Now I'm stuck.  I'm not sure how else to grab the data from the list, as it doesn't seem to be appearing anywhere accessible.  I've included a screenshot of the window in question, if its any help.

[image]

Comment: If it is not a ListView then it is a custom grid control.  You're done, you can't read that.

Comment: Drats, that was what I was fearing.

Comment: Try the UI Spy tool (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms727247.aspx). There is also another tool that you can try: SysExporter (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sysexp.html). If these tools can read it, it's possible to do it, otherwise you probably can't.

Answer (score 1):

using QTP Quick Test Professional ver 10, you can get the values inside the probrowser object. You should use `<probrowser Object Reference>.GetVisibleText.`

We are using the same in our automation scripts.